# Threads to perform only print certain numbers of range

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a 2 threads ,they want to perform some process in this way

```
Public Class MyThread implements Runnable{
in public void run(){

for(int i=0;i<=20;i++)
//t1 thread will come & print 1 to 10 numbers only
//t2 thread will come & print next numbers i.e 11 to 20 only. 

}

}

public Class MainClass{

public static void main(String arg[]){

MyThread obj=new MyThread();
Thread t1=new Thread(obj);
Thread t2=new Thread(obj);
t1.start();
t2.start();

}
}
```

How can I restrict my threads to print only numbers with conditions mentioned in run() method ?

Answer (score 3):

That's not how it works; use something like this.

```
class NumberPrinter implements Runnable
{

    private final int start, end;

    public NumberPrinter(int start, int end)
    {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        for (int i = start; i <= end; ++i)
            System.out.println(i);
    } 
}
```

Calling:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new NumberPrinter(1, 10));
Thread t2 = new Thread(new NumberPrinter(11, 20));
t1.start();
t2.start();
```

Of course you will have to expand this example (e.g. check whether the start value is less than end's), but this gives you a rough idea.